# How to create and edit multiple classes and objects in Parse with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, parse-osx-sdk

I will explain my scenario. I dont know how to do that. 
I loaded my contacts in the app. Now I want to create group with my friends. I want to send request to them to accept the group. If accepted they must be added to the Group. My friends must see their groups. The one they created and accepted. 
Any one can create any number of groups with any number of members.

So how can I do that? By creating single class called Group and inside the class add all the groups as objects? Or create a separate class for each Group created? If so million classes will be created in my app! Will Parse allow that?

Is there any restriction for number of classes or objects in Parse?

Please explain with some code or image if possible...

Comment: Very broad... Try creating a suitable data model first and asking about that (probably on the review site), then trying to start populating it. Think about a group class as something to hold a relationship to users (or two for approved and pending users). You need to think in terms of OOP.